# cropping an image via a php file

Tags: php, image, crop

so i have an image that is originally 1696x1696. i want to use a php file to MIME a png file. what i want the php to do is crop the original file and produce a quarter of the image. Later i plan to use $_GET variables to return which quadrant i want, but for testing/debugging, im just aiming to get the top left quadrant.

here's the code:

```
Header("Content-type:image/png");
$newImg =imagecreatefrompng('test.png'); 

//manually entered half height and width
$img=imagecreatetruecolor(848,848);
//here is where the bugs keep flawing the image
imagecopyresampled($img,$newImg,0,0,0,0,1696,1696,1696,1696);
imagepng($img); 
imagedestroy($img);
```

this will produce the image (top, left) like it's supposed to, however it adds several smaller resampled images on top of it. no matter how i toy with it, i cant get it right. i've also tried imagecopy() and cant get it right as well. looked up tutorials and i cant seem to find on that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. The only thing I would change is to use `imagecopyresized()` instead of `imagecopyresampled()` in this use case.

```
Header("Content-type:image/png");
$source = imagecreatefrompng('images/test.png'); 

// manually entered half height and width
$thumb  = imagecreatetruecolor(848,848);

imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1696, 1696, 1696, 1696);
imagepng($thumb); 
imagedestroy($thumb);
```

I am guessing that earlier in your tests, you were overwriting your original image. That would explain the...

> however it adds several smaller resampled images on top of it...

...part of your experience. Each time you ran the code, you picked up the previously modified file.

Comment: this was it! once i got the original back the way it was supposed to be, the "cropped" images fell in place. after manually entering in which quadrant i wanted, i went back and set it up so the $_GET variables would specify which one i wanted to return. 

this was to create a leaflet map that utilized 1 large picture to create the tiles. i want php to do the tile butchering at the map's request. i ended up just using imagecopy() function to make it happen. the imagecopyresize() was the one i bugged and originally messed up my .png file.

Comment: Great news! If you have PHP 5.5 at your disposal, you can simplify things even more with imagecrop() http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecrop.php

Answer (score 0):

ok, so after enough headbanging and hair-tearing out, i decided to just go back to photoshop and overwrite the .png with my original .psd. starting to get somewhere now. i got my quadrant without all the ridiculousness. when i get a better understanding, i might come back and explain where i kept going wrong